# Laravel: unexpected GET request

Tags: laravel, get-request

I am logging errors in a Laravel website.

I saw some errors like this: *Error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.*

Into log I also save the previous page with request()->headers->get('referer') and it is empty.

I double checked and the only call to that route is done with POST method.

Moreover the page with the form (that calls that route with POST) needs a login (middleware('auth') in Controller's construct), so bots or others should not get the action attribute and use it with GET.

Could you help me, please?

EDIT
web.php

```
<?php
    Route::prefix('/{coNameURL}/extranet')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'Extranet\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('extranet.home');
        Route::get('/login', 'Extranet\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('extranet.login');
        Route::post('/login', 'Extranet\Auth\LoginController@login');
        Route::post('/logout', 'Extranet\Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('extranet.logout');
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'Extranet\HomeController@dashboard')->name('extranet.dashboard');
        Route::get('/moduli/{blocco}/segnalazione', 'Extranet\ModuliController@modulo')->name('extranet.moduli.segnalazione');
        Route::post('/moduli/{blocco}/invia_segnalazione', 'Extranet\ModuliController@modulo_invia')->name('extranet.moduli.blocco_invia');
    });
```

EDIT: error

```
C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER>php artisan cache:clear
Application cache cleared!



C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER>php artisan route:cache
Route cache cleared!

   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919|
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Routing\Route::prepareForSerialization()
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:62

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::handle()
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.



C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER>php artisan route:cache -v
Route cache cleared!

   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919|
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Routing\Route::prepareForSerialization()
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:62

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::handle()
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36

  3   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:37

  4   Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:93

  5   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:37

  6   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:590

  7   Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:134

  8   Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:255

  9   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:121

  10  Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:1009

  11  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:273

  12  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:149

  13  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:93

  14  Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:131

  15  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\inetpub\WEBSITE_FOLDER\artisan:37
```

Comment: This error is straight to the point. You are using a GET request on a route which responds to POST in your `web.php` file (or another one if you're not using it)

Comment: Can you share your web.php file please?!

Comment: You are getting that error on which route?

Comment: @Andrea I am a bit confused. The route is defined as a POST request, hence you must send a post request. Are you saying that you are getting this error even after sending a post request to that route?

Comment: @Zihad no, I can't replicate that error, but I saw it in my log file.

Comment: try to log the url as well that's causing the error. in your \APP\Exceptions\Handler.php override the context() method. It will be easier to detect the origin of the error. 

protected function context(): array
    {
                 return array_merge(parent::context(),['request_url'=>request()->url()] );
    }

Comment: @Zihad I am logging that, it is: .../xyx/extranet/moduli/656/invia_segnalazione
as expected is like someone is calling the route (named "extranet.moduli.blocco_invia") with GET

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the (route) cache?

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried it now and got an error: see main post edit

Comment: @Andrea the same error like before?

Comment: No, it is an error in command line, I edited main post just now, sorry

Comment: @Andrea ok. my mistake. you cant cache route closures. but you clearing the cache was successfully. The problems still there? Then you can run `composer dump autoload` . To exclude any problems that may occur here.

Comment: I am a bit scared to run that command, the website is in Laravel 6, is it safe?

Comment: @Andrea You don't have to be scared.  This command is a useful and frequently used command. Nothing is installed or deleted. It simply goes over your classes and indexes them.

Comment: site went down after i ran that command showing this message: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running 7.2.7. I temporaly fixed adding "platform-check": false in composer.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243684/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-andrea).

Comment: @Andrea It seems that are some open issues in your app.

Comment: @Andrea It could be that some patrts of your frontend make a get Request. You can check with your browser developer tool.